# How to get info of class call order in Python?

Tags: python

How to get the classes information of `A` and `B` and the order of their invocations `A` followed by `B` in the following Python code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self):
        return self.x + self.y

class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __call__(self):
        return self.x - self.y


Class C:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self):
        a = A(2, 3)
        b = B(a(), 3)
        return b
```

Given, `C`, how to find out that the two module 'C()`uses are`A`and`B`and the order their executions is`A`followed by`B`?

Comment: A.__init__, then a(), then B.__init__ then b()

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you are asking exactly. What, exactly, is the output you want?

Comment: Updated the question. Basically, given class C ( say, as an argument to a function), I want to find what are the classes used to calculate the output of C() and also in what order.

Comment: That's what `logging` is for. Or profilers if you are interested in it only during development.

Comment: No this not just for profiling. In that other function, I want to detect that class A and B are used and A followed by B. Then I want to programmatically replace B with another class `D`. So the modified C's call will look like `d(a(), 3, 54)`

Comment: This toy example uses only two classes. I actually production env, I expect class `C` to be composed of 50 classes.

Comment: The answer is still the same, just C.__init__ before everything else. Class C being composed of 50 classes is not the same as Class C instantiating classes inside. I'll ask again is there inheritance involved? Because you don't mention this in your code. If you want help post code that matches your problem, don't post code and then say "My actual code is not like this it's more like X" because then we can't help. IF there is no inheritance involved then the only option is that the classes call order is just however they've been written. If class A is before class B then A is called before B.

Comment: There is no inheritance involved. Yes, C.__init__ before everything else is correct, but that is not something I was looking at. My question is, how do I decompose the call sequence into its constituent classes and then replace a few of those constituent classes with new classes to obtain a new execution order.